# Detecting if React PHP client cannot connect to server

Tags: php, sockets, reactphp

How can it be detected that a React PHP client cannot connect with a server?  I was hoping for the fictional `else()` method that I showed at the bottom.  Do I just need to wait a reasonable amount of time, and if no `on data` event occurs, it isn't connected.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$dnsResolverFactory = new React\Dns\Resolver\Factory();
$dns = $dnsResolverFactory->createCached('8.8.8.8', $loop);
$connector = new React\SocketClient\Connector($loop, $dns);

$connector->create('127.0.0.1', 1337)->then(function (React\Stream\Stream $stream) {
    $buffer = '';
    $stream->on('data', function ($data, $stream) use (&$buffer) {
    });
})
/*
->else(function () {
    //no connection?
});
*/

$loop->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at ReactPHP's [`PromiseInterface`](https://github.com/reactphp/promise/blob/d726517fea40ec878e1ed6e495b698a8a6b8b91e/src/PromiseInterface.php). Either use a second callback for `then` or use `otherwise`, which is exactly your artificial `else`.

```
$connector->create('127.0.0.1', 1337)->then(function (React\Stream\Stream $stream) {
    $buffer = '';
    $stream->on('data', function ($data, $stream) use (&$buffer) {
        // ...
    });
}, function (Throwable $error) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Perfect!  Also, thanks for pointing me to the `PromiseInterface`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$dnsResolverFactory = new React\Dns\Resolver\Factory();
$dns = $dnsResolverFactory->createCached('8.8.8.8', $loop);
$connector = new React\SocketClient\Connector($loop, $dns);

$gotConnected=false;

$connector->create('127.0.0.1', 1337)->then(function (React\Stream\Stream $stream) use(&$gotConnected) {
    $gotConnected=true;
    $buffer = '';
    $stream->on('data', function ($data, $stream) use (&$buffer) {
    });
});

$loop->run();

echo($gotConnected?'Got connected':'Did not get connected');
```

Comment: While this works for a single socket, there's a better way to handle errors, [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43968729/2373138).